# Optimizing query still takes a bit long time

Tags: sql, db2

How to optimize this query? I have tried using `LEFT JOIN` clause but still take at least 3 seconds.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MBLNR
FROM MKPF
WHERE MANDT='368'
     AND XBLNR = '0150525913'
     AND MBLNR NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT SMBLN FROM MSEG WHERE XBLNR_MKPF = '0150525913' )
```

After using `LEFT JOIN`, still takes 3 seconds to get the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.MBLNR
FROM MKPF AS A
LEFT JOIN MSEG AS B ON B.XBLNR_MKPF=A.XBLNR AND A.MBLNR <> B.SMBLN
WHERE A.XBLNR = '0150525913'
```

Using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` really takes much time to return the rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Try doing an outer join on the second table. Also, do you these have indexed?

Comment: @BRogers: `left outer join` takes more time to return the rows. Yes, it has indexed..

Comment: i) Hope your query is correct.I mean you know what output you want.
ii) you are sure to use left join instead of inner and you are also sure about distinct .
iii) Index is define on MANDT,XBLNR ,XBLNR_MKPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct left outer join formulation of the first query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.MBLNR
FROM MKPF A LEFT JOIN
     MSEG B
     ON B.SMBLN = A.MBLNR AND AND B.XBLNR_MKPF = '0150525913'
WHERE A.XBLNR = '0150525913' and A.MANDT='368' and B.SMBLN is null;
```

Depending on the sizes of the tables, 3 seconds might be reasonable.  However, you can speed the query by using indexes.  This query suggests some indexes:  `MKPF(XBLNR, MANDT, MBLNR)` and `MSEG(XBLNR_MKPF, SMBLN)`.

Comment: It's better but still only a little bit cutoff. Btw, thanks, ;)

Answer (score 0):

While intuitive, "not in" is slow.  So,  change this:

```
 AND MBLNR NOT IN 
( SELECT DISTINCT SMBLN FROM MSEG WHERE XBLNR_MKPF = '0150525913' )
```

to

```
AND MBLNR IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT MBLNR
FROM MKPF
WHERE MANDT='368'
AND XBLNR = '0150525913'
except
SELECT DISTINCT SMBLN 
FROM MSEG 
WHERE XBLNR_MKPF = '0150525913' 
)
```

Comment: It takes really long time to get the result.. >O<

Answer (score 0):

why are you using distinct and left.If they really require then its ok .or you can use inner join without distinct .Specially sub query do not require distinct .

```
you can try not exists
SELECT MBLNR
FROM MKPF
WHERE MANDT='368'
     AND XBLNR = '0150525913'
     AND  NOT exists ( SELECT SMBLN FROM MSEG WHERE  XBLNR_MKPF = '0150525913' )
```